# Android version support for push notifications

Tags: c#, .net, android

Need help for implementing PUSH notification in android. wanted to know from which android version, push notification will be supported. When i searched for the Android notification service in android, i saw C2DM which will be supported after android 2.2.

If it will be supported after 1.5, please let me know what are the options available to achieve push notification for 1.5 and above.

Thanks in Advance
Srinivasan

Comment: It seems like you kind of answered your own question. Are you looking for *alternatives* to C2DM in Android versions older than 2.2? As far as I'm aware, there isn't going to be a way to actually achieve it unless you're developing for Froyo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For below 2.2, there is no native support in Android. You will have to use some third party push notification services like [urbanship](http://urbanairship.com/homepage/) or mqtt described [here](http://tokudu.com/2010/how-to-implement-push-notifications-for-android/)

For a good explanation of google c2dm (native push support from google), see [this](http://techtej.blogspot.com/2010/10/android-c2dm-messaging-server-push-for.html).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you could use [WebORB](http://themidnightcoders.com/products.html) to do data push from Java or .NET to Android (Native Java and AIR). Here is a [link](http://blog.themidnightcoders.com/index.php/2011/04/15/developing-android-apps-with-weborb/) to more information and videos about using WebORB messaging with for Android.